# Create Localized Email Recommendation Displays - Salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein-recommendations, localization

I want to create localized email recommendation displays in Salesforce marketing cloud.

Only documentation I can find is: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_localized_recommendations.htm&type=5 And only 'localized pricing' is mentioned under Displays.

**A localized ProductName and ProductLink is not possible?**

[image]

I created Localized fields in my Product catalog, but they don't are accessible in the 'Add an identifier' field in de Product Display Builder. When I add the "?locale=nl-be" parameter, the ProductName disappears.

[image]

Is it possible and how do I get it to work?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your display you should simply have `%%ProductName%%`

In your recommendations call you should pass the locale similar to this:

`https://XXXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/XXXXXXXXX/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?locale=%%localevalue%%`

And then in your sending DE you should have values for localevalue like nl-be